# Get deal with node that have NO namespace

Tags: java, xml, xpath, namespaces

Recently, we have trouble with some unusual XML. 
Suppose, XML looks like

```
<rootNode>
    <childNode xmlns = "http://default.namespace.com">
        <targetNode>
            some_text
        </targetNode>
    </childNode>
</rootNode>
```

and our target to get **some_text** from this XML by XPath.
As you can see, **rootNode** did not has namespace at all, but another nodes have default namespace.

In general, our approach to XPath (in NameSpace context) are follows: we firstly loop throw document and collect all namespaces and prefixes. Then we set set this info to **NamespaceContext**, and calculate XPath. And feel happy until this.

In this case, such XPath to get **some_text**

```
/rootNode/childNode/targetNode
```

didn't work, cause Java treats that **rootNode** has also http://default.namespace.com namespace, which is incorrect.

So, question is: how to write correct XPath in this case?

So far, we found only this workaround: wrote something like

```
/NonExistingPrefix:rootNode/childNode/targetNode
```

This is works, because of document does not have namespace with **NonExistingPrefix**, and because of this Java treats

```
/NonExistingPrefix:rootNode
```

as

```
pure /rootNode without namespace
```

- exactly what we need.

But this approach looks quite ugly.

Comment: How about this: `/rootNode/ns:childNode/ns:targetNode`.

Comment: No, this is vise versa what we need. By this, `rootNode` theats as have default namespace, and `childNode, targetNode` have no namespace

Comment: Unprefixed names in XPath 1.0 always mean "no namespace". Use prefix that point to default namespace uri in XPath instead of just element name without prefix.

Comment: **Kachna**, sorry for late answer. We use XPath 2.0, definite Saxon HE. And unprefixed names resolves to default namespace (if we add default namespace to NamespaceContext).